# Java transferFrom Part of binary file?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

Im tring to transfer from a file filein starting at position 1300 (in uint8 pieces) into fileto, using the RandomAccessFile transferFrom function.

```
fromfile = java.io.RandomAccessFile(ifile, 'rw');
fromchannel = fromfile.getChannel();
tofile = java.io.RandomAccessFile(ofile, 'rw');
tochannel = tofile.getChannel();
tochannel.transferFrom(fromchannel,n,fromfile.length()-n)

tochannel.close();
fromchannel.close();
fromfile.close();
tofile.close();
```

My output file is just empty tho.

Anyone know what im doing wrong??

Edit 1:

I've changed

```
tochannel.transferFrom(fromchannel,n,fromfile.length()-n)
```

to

```
fromchannel.transferTo(n,fromfile.length()-n,tochannel)
```

But now the output is printing to the all the file right except for it puts alot of 00 hexadecimals where the header in the original was???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `transferTo` I believe

```
fromchannel.transferTo(n,fromfile.length()-n,tochannel)
```

as `transferFrom` tries to start at position n in the outfile, while `transferTo` will start at position n in the infile

Comment: Ok, I changed the order tho to fromchannel.transferTo(n,fromfile.length()-n,tochannel). Its working except that the output file has alot of zeros at the start where the deleted header was??? Any Ideas

Comment: I'm not sure what would be causing you to get zeros at the start? Switching to a java.io.FileOutputStream might help.